# Can I lazy load Less files, and still use variables?

Tags: javascript, less

So I have this function which can lazy load Less files:

```
var addLess = function(url) {
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="' + url + '" />');
  var newStyle = $('link[href="' + url + '"]').get(0);
  less.sheets.push(newStyle);
  less.refresh();
}
```

But if I have a var in my main less file which is already loaded when I call addLess

```
@valentine: #ef26ac;
```

I am unable to reference the var when I call addLess

```
.content {
  background: @valentine;
}
```

This throws

```
NameError: variable @valentine is undefined
```

Does anybody see a way I may be able to get around this?

Comment: Do all of them share the same work space?

Comment: @Joraid I dunno what you mean by that... is that an internal less thing? They are all in the same document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LESS does not read variables "across" files that are loaded into html (as your lazy loading is doing). At the time less is loaded, it becomes just css.

For a less file to read a variable from another less file, that other less file must be `@imported` into the first file in the less code itself.

So you should have a "variables.less" file or something similar, and `@import` that file into every less file that may need a variable from it.